# ReflectionOnlyLoad and GetField

Tags: c#

If I load an assembly via Assembly.Load I can iterate thru its types, look for a specific type by typef(...).IsAssignableFrom and get field information via GetField from a type.

As I load the assembly for reflection only I tried ReflectionOnlyLoad instead of load. The first problem was IsAssignableFrom always reporting false, but GetInterface did the job. The second problem I did not find a solution for is GetField always returning null.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue with IsAssignableFrom always returning false, but did some experimenting and found a workaround.  The key is to make sure both types in the comparison are in a ReflectionlyOnly context.

In other words, this doesn't work in general:

```
var types = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(assemblyName).GetExportedTypes();
foreach( var t in types )
{
    bool check = SomeBaseType.IsAssignableFrom(t);
}
```

This seems to always give `check=false`, but I think that's because `t` is in a reflection-only context but `SomeBaseType` is not.

The workaround I found was to load the base class's assembly in a reflection-only context, then find the equivalent base type in that context.  Then we can do the comparison where both types are reflection-only:

```
var baseAssembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(typeof(SomeBaseType).Assembly.FullName);
var baseTypes = baseAssembly.GetExportedTypes();
var reflectionOnlyBaseType = Array.Find(baseTypes,(t)=>(t.FullName==typeof(SomeBaseType).FullName));
var types = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(assemblyName).GetExportedTypes();
foreach( var t in types )
{
    bool check = reflectionOnlyBaseType.IsAssignableFrom(t);
}
```

This seems to give the expected result.  There may be a more efficient way to get to that reflection-only context without reloading the assembly (I'm no C# expert), but that was the easiest way I could find.

The same approach seems to work for both IsSubclassOf and IsAssignableFrom.

Comment: Thank you! Helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use IsAssignableFrom with assemblies loaded through RefelectionOnlyLoad/ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom because IsAssignableFrom uses Type comparative methods, such as IsSubclassOf. Internally it does make a call to GetInterfaces via the internal ImplementInterface method, but that's about it.

As for as your GetField call, what binding flags are you passing in? If you are not passing any in, is the field public?  Typically by design, most fields should be private/internal, so you need to make sure the right binding flags are passed to the GetField method.

Comment: This is what I am using. It works with Load, but not with ReflectionOnlyLoad.

FieldInfo fieldInfo = t.GetField ("strReleaseCS", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

Answer (score 0):

I used an extension method to see if two types are equal, which just compares the `AssemblyQualifiedName` property. It's not bullet-proof, but it's definitely good enough:

```
public static bool ReflectionOnlyEquals(this Type type, Type otherType)
{
  return type.AssemblyQualifiedName == otherType.AssemblyQualifiedName;
}
```

Then I can just call something like this, for example:

```
bool equal = currType.ReflectionOnlyEquals(typeof(string));
```