# Why does interface comparison fail with Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom() and not with Assembly.LoadFrom()?

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

My code is scanning various directories for plugin DLLs. They are recognisable because they have an exported type implementing `IBehaviourPlugin`.

Following several online posts, I've tried loading the assemblies with the following code (file loop stripped out for readability):

```
    // Plugin interface
    Type behaviourPlugin = typeof(OrganShared.IBehaviourPlugin);

    // Load assembly from file
    Assembly a = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(f);
    Type[] exports = a.GetExportedTypes();
    int validTypes = (from Type t in exports
                          where behaviourPlugin.IsAssignableFrom(t)
                          && behaviourPlugin.FullName != t.FullName
                          select t).Count();
    if (validTypes > 0) { files.Add(new FileInfo(f)); }
```

This fails to identify any assemblies which fit the criteria. **However**, if I replace `Assembly a = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(f);` with `Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(f);`, the types compare perfectly, and all my plugin DLLs are identified correctly.

Can anyone explain to me the reason for this different behaviour? It's not my first outing with reflection, but this one is a bit beyond me.

Incidentally, behaviour is the same if I use the alternate method of checking: `t.GetInterfaces().Contains(IBehaviourPlugin)`

Lastly, I'm not currently creating a new AppDomain for the reflection - I suspect I can / should / will need to, but I wanted to isolate this behaviour before potentially adding further complication.

Comment: read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: "Dependencies are not automatically loaded into the reflection-only context. To automatically load dependencies, handle the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event and load the dependency in the event handler."

Comment: Something that may be important to note: _You cannot execute code from an assembly that has been loaded into the reflection-only context_

Comment: Thanks, @JohnB - I did run into that error at one point too. It's not the presenting issue here, though - and the MS docs are silent on the actual solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another thread that is similar [ReflectionOnlyLoad and GetField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008097/reflectiononlyload-and-getfield)
It seems that check doesn't work if base type is not obtained by an assebly not loaded in  ReflectionlyOnly mode.
So try to load IBehaviourPlugin type in this way.

```
var baseAssembly = assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(typeof(OrganShared.IBehaviourPlugin).Assembly.FullName);
var baseTypes = baseAssembly.GetExportedTypes();
var reflectionOnlyBaseType = Array.Find(baseTypes,(t)=>(t.FullName==typeof(OrganShared.IBehaviourPlugin).FullName));
```

then change

```
behaviourPlugin.IsAssignableFrom(t)
```

with

```
reflectionOnlyBaseType.IsAssignableFrom(t)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Let's figure that out.

- `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom()` only loads your assembly to reflection-only context.

It means that your library is being loaded for analysis purposes only.
It's used to load 64-bit assembly in 32-bit application. You can view types, methods, properties but you will not be able to execute it's code.

When you load assembly that way your `Assembly` object will have [`ReflectionOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononly?view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_Assembly_ReflectionOnly) property set to `true`.

Normal assembly loading via `.LoadFile()` will load all code from assembly and make it ready to execute.

#### What happens when you try to compare them?

**UPDATE!** Figured it out. Was simpler than I thought.

Normal type object has type `System.RuntimeType` and other reflection-only type has type `System.ReflectionOnlyType`. Mystery solved.

Comment: Thanks. This is the right reasoning, but I will accept @Roberto's answer, as he has also laid out how to adapt the code.